# First movie that collaborated with fast-food outlets?

Tags: first-appearance, marketing, gremlins

In 1984, the movie **Gremlins** teamed up with **Hardees** to sell a set of LPs that came along with the movie:

[image]

Each week a different record would be sold, thus, each week, parents had to take their children to Hardees to get the latest one.

What was the first movie to team up with fast-food to do something like this?  What was the product they sold?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [KFFT List Guide](http://www.kathysfastfoodtoys.com/wordpress/?page_id=113) says:

> Burger King was a pioneer in the
>   advertising practice known as the
>   product tie-in with a successful
>   partnering with George Lucas’
>   Lucasfilm, Ltd. to promote the 1977
>   film Star Wars in which BK sold a set of glasses featuring the main characters
>   from the film. This promotion was one
>   of the first in the fast food industry and
>   set the pattern that continues to the
>   present.

And from Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burger_King_advertising :

> Burger King's first successful cross- promotional campaign was in 1977. It offered several collectible items, such as
>   posters, glasses and sticker sets that
>   featured scenes and characters from Star Wars.

Here's some [photos of the 1978 posters and cups](http://www.kathysfastfoodtoys.com/wordpress/?p=165) and [cups from 1977](http://www.rebelscum.com/bk1977glasses.asp).

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if it was the first time that *any* movie teamed up with a fast food restaurant, but the first ever themed promotion for McDonald's Happy Meal was for [Star Trek: The Motion Picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Motion_Picture) in 1979.  From the [Happy Meal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Meal#History) Wikipedia article:

> The packaging used for the Star Trek Meal consisted of various images and games related to the film, as well as a comic strip adaptation of the film. Consumers had to buy numerous meals in order to complete the set.

I found an image of the toy communicator from that Happy Meal in the article [The 50 Coolest Happy Meal Toys of All Time](http://www.complex.com/city-guide/2012/01/the-50-coolest-happy-meal-toys-of-all-time#31).

[image: Star Trek Happy Meal Toy - 1979]

Answer (score 1):

The first Star wars tie in was Burger Chef not Burger King.

Comment: Couldn't it have been both?